# Select all the values other than distinct mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to `mysql` I am having hard time to prepare a query which will return all the items remaining the distinct items
For Example:

TableName : `City`

Fields are : `id,name,population`

I want to get all the city names which are not distinct 
i was trying some thing like this but it gives me an error

```
SELECT S.CITY FROM STATION AS S LEFT JOIN STATION ON (SELECT DISTINCT(P.CITY) FROM STATION AS P)
```

can some one guide me over this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city) AS count
FROM station
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(city) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

distinct is not a function but a clause
and if you want use distinct you could try using a subquery left jont  where don't match

```
SELECT S.CITY 
FROM STATION AS S 
LEFT JOIN STATION ON ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
     FROM STATION 
) T  S.CITY  = T.CITY 
where t.city is null
```

but aso group by city and javing count(*)  = 1

```
SELECT CITY 
FROM STATION 
GROUP BY city
having count(*) = 1
```